# biblatex control file version newer than expected

Tags: biblatex, biber, ubuntu

**Edit**: I found the solution - see below for details.

I'm having a problem running biber (see below).

```
$ biber  thesis-base
INFO - This is Biber 0.9.9
INFO - Logfile is 'thesis-base.blg'
INFO - Reading 'thesis-base.bcf'
WARN - Warning: Found biblatex control file version 2.5, expected version 1.7
INFO - Found 21 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing bib section 0
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'referenser.bib' for section 0
INFO - Decoding LaTeX character macros into UTF-8
INFO - Finished Decoding LaTeX character macros into UTF-8
INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'referenser.bib'
INFO - Sorting list 'MAIN' keys
INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'en_US.UTF-8'
INFO - Writing 'thesis-base.bbl' with encoding 'UTF-8'
INFO - Output to thesis-base.bbl
INFO - WARNINGS: 1
```

I'm Ubuntu (3.11.0-12-generic) with Texlive installed from the website. As far as I can tell `tlmgr` is fully upated (revision 31673). Running `tlmgr update --all` does not resolve this problem. And I, as a result, cannot compile the LaTeX file.

Please advice.

**Edit**: found a solution (I include a long description for those who repeat the mistake):

I had originally installed both texlive and biber as ubuntu packages. When I realised texlive didn't play well, I removed the texlive package and installed it directly using the `www.tug.org/texlive` website but I forgot to also remove the biber package (as it's included with texlive). My PATH environment variable was set to:

`PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-linux`

which meant the outdated ubuntu version of biber was used rather than the newer texlive version. I solved this by verifying ubuntu biber was installed:

```
# which biber
/usr/bin/biber
# dpkg -S /usr/bin/biber
biber: /usr/bin/biber
```

and then simply removing the ubuntu version:

```
# apt-get --purge remove biber
```

and it's working flawlessly now. (current biber version is 1.8).

Comment: Your biber is much to old and is certainly not the biber from a current texlive.

Comment: While your tlmgr may be current, are you sure you connect to a current package-repository?

Comment: current biber version is 1.8

Comment: Is your path set correctly?

Comment: Thanks to you guys I realised I had two versions of biber installed. Removed the older one and it works now. Yay!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using an outdated version of biber

Comment: @Guido why is an outdated version of `biber` off topic? Some people are forced to work with old versions of things.

Comment: @StrongBad because the problem can be solved by updating to a more recent version.

Comment: @Guido Sure, but in the context of, say, Ubuntu/Mint, the most recent version didn't solve the problem. I had to solve it by going elsewhere (directly to Texlive sources).